# Sudo a bash script in profile.d

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, redhat

Using RedHat 6, the following script is located in /etc/profile.d/my_custom_script.sh

```
function checkroot {
  if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Sorry, you are not root."
    return
  else
    echo "You've got the powah!"
  fi
}
```

as a normal user, and as root, the `checkroot` command runs as expected.

However, when running 
`sudo checkroot` either as a normal user with sudo privileges, or as root itself, the system responds with
`sudo: checkroot: command not found`

The command runs successfully with `sudo -i checkroot`, however I don't want to have to provide this option to sudo. What needs to change to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible since sudo does not allow functions to be exported through itself. You can save the function to a script file instead and run sudo with it:

```
#!/bin/bash
function checkroot {
  if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Sorry, you are not root."
    return
  else
    echo "You've got the powah!"
  fi
}
checkroot
```

Run:

```
sudo bash script.sh
```

Optionally you can juse place the commands directly

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Sorry, you are not root."
else
    echo "You've got the powah!"
fi
```

You can place that in `~/.bashrc` as well at your preference so that it would run everytime an interactive shell is called.

Comment: And I assume from there I could move the script into the system-wide bin folder and execute it as a native command, correct?

Comment: @colsen Yes you can do that. Just make sure you add executable permission on it with chmod. And `/usr/local/bin` is preferrable.